# How to write DTD with avoiding order of elements?

Tags: xml, dtd

I want to validate following XML. Where a branch can have no or multiple managers and/or accountants. Their order is random. What I have tried is as follows:

```
 <!ELEMENT branch (office, manager*, accountant*)>
```

But I am getting error, and I know above statement is making order strict. How can I avoid the order of manager and accountant.

The XML:

```
<branch name = "south">
<office>
    <addr>St. 32, Downtown</addr>
</office>
<manager>
    <username>
        knitemorgan
    </username>
</manager>
<accountant>
    <username>
        johnsmith
    </username>
</accountant>
<manager>
    <username>
        jenifer
    </username>
</manager>
<accountant>
    <username>
        fclark
    </username>
</accountant>
   <branch>
  <branch name = "north">
<office>
    <addr>St. 328, Downtown</addr>
</office>
<accountant>
    <username>
        rogerbentley
    </username>
</accountant>
<manager>
    <username>
        wendymaria
    </username>
</manager>
    <branch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<!ELEMENT branch (office,(manager|accountant)*)>
```

This means exactly one `office` followed by zero or more `manager` or `accountant`.

Order doesn't matter with the `manager` or `accountant` because of the `|`.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be aware that content models can have models nested within them.  So something like this should work

```
<!ELEMENT branch (office, (manager | accountant )*) >
```

However, as a rule, it's poor design not to group repeating elements into a distinct container element: you will find the processing easier to manage if you do so.

```
<!ELEMENT branch (office, staff) >
<!ELEMENT staff (manager|accountant)*>
```